# Batch: Save multiple files with same extension but in another directory

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a script that saves all the files processed by the batch at the same time, with the same extension (.P3D) but in another directory, I tried this but it did not work, please help me

**bat1.bat:**

```
set var=1 0
start cmd goto /k bat2
```

**bat2.bat**

```
set src_folder=C:\Users\kaue9\Desktop\ResLodRemover\OriginalPlants2Trees  
set dst_folder=C:\Users\kaue9\Desktop\ResLodRemover\teste

for /R %src_folder% %%f in (*.p3d) do ResLodRemover.exe %%f %dst_folder%\*.p3d %var%
```

the problem is in     `%dst_folder%`, ty guys

Comment: You haven't given enough information about what you expect/want to happen, versus what is actually happening when you run your code. probably Not related to your code failure, but the `goto` in your "bat1.bat" is totally non-functional (invalid syntax in that context, but harmless).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best guess:

**bat1.cmd**

```bat
@SET "var=1 0"
@CALL "bat2.cmd" "%var%"
```

**bat2.cmd**

```bat
@SET "src_folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\ResLodRemover\OriginalPlants2Trees"
@SET "dst_folder=%UserProfile%\Desktop\ResLodRemover\teste"

@FOR /R "%src_folder%" %%A IN (*.p3d
) DO @ResLodRemover.exe "%%~A" "%dst_folder%\%%~nxA" %~1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I needed, thank you friend.